# Looking for the right Tools for developing a website with SPA components in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, single-page-application

i am a new Webdeveloper and im struggeling to find the right tools and frameworks to use for the specific site i am building.
Its a site for managing all kind of information and documents about clients my firm cares for.

It consists of general information (like statistics etc.) that should be served synchronously and a client specific part that should be a SPA (mainly because i want to have a list of all clients on the side, so that the main part of the page updates when you click one).

My problem is , that there is so much information about that kind of stuff (but not specificly a project comparable to mine), so that i can't decide what the best approach would be.

I found those options so far:

- Just serve everything with django and update reactive parts of the page with Ajax
- building a dedicated Frontend and with Frameworks like Svelte or React and using Django as API.
- Using these Frameworks just for the critical components that have to be reactive and serving everything with django

If i understand correctly, the cleanest way would be Nr. 2, but i would lose access to djangos form rendering with crispy_forms (which, for a website consisting mainly of forms, would kinda suck).
The same is kinda true for Option 3 i think, since the critical Elements are mostly forms. And as far is i know you cant render django forms as react components.

I was discouraged from using Option 1, cause it seems to very error-prone to build a SPA without a framework.

I would really appreciate some input from more experienced People like me to help me with the decicion which path to go down.
Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, but it all depends on your knowledge and deadline.
Don't try to make everything perfect at once. Make an MVP using the technologies that you are familiar with and show the working version to the management. I'm sure there will be many edits and improvements that they will want to implement.

If you need an advise about stack, then you can look at Django + DRF + Vue.js

Comment: Oh thanks! I was already looking into Django+DRf but React instead of vue.... but it seems like a lot of extra work , considering i just need some forms recieving data asynchronusly... i look into vue :D